# Angular 16 (Material) trying to create an identifier to html element using a variable

Tags: angular, material-design

I'm trying to creaet a dynamic menu using mat-menu elements and asigning an identifier with a variable. [matMenuTriggerFor] don't reconize this identifier

Values for menu are:

```
    this.menuAyuda.push(['General']);
    this.menuAyuda.push(['Expedientes', ['Alta Expediente', 'Alta Lote', 'Alta Línea Adjudicación', 'Alta Línea Renovación', 'Recepción Administrativa', 'Recepción a Inventario']]);
    this.menuAyuda.push(['Inventario', ['Búsquedas','Mover Artículos entre Unidades', 'Asignar CUF-Sistema-Subsistema']]);
```

and html to build the menu:

```
   <ng-container *ngFor="let seccion of menuAyuda">
        <span *ngIf="!seccion[1] || seccion[1]?.length == 0">
          <button mat-menu-item>{{seccion[0]}}</button>
        </span>
        <ng-container *ngIf="!!seccion[1] && seccion[1]?.length > 0">
          <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="seccion[0]">{{seccion[0]}}</button>
          <mat-menu ref-{{seccion[0]}}="matMenu">
            <span *ngFor="let subitem of seccion[1]">
              <button mat-menu-item>{{subitem}}</button>
            </span>
          </mat-menu>
          <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="seccion[0]">{{seccion[0]}}</button>
          <mat-menu ref-{{seccion[0]}}="matMenu">
            patata
            <span *ngFor="let subitem of seccion[1]">
              <button mat-menu-item>{{subitem}}</button>
            </span>
          </mat-menu>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
```

Comment: I'm used too #{{seccion[0]}}  to set the identifier on mat-menu element

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: Well, probably need more explanation,  the problem is the identificacion attribute of <mat-menu...> tag.
If use literal (#menuexp for example) it work's fine. In this case is asigned using an expression (ref-{{seccion[0]}} or @{{seccion[0]}}, is the same ) and it does'nt work. 
So this is my real question (see title), 
How to set an identifier (# or ref-, no other) from an expression?

Comment: Excuse me, Vega, i forgot answer at your question:  the output is an overlay with all options included in <mat-menu tag.  It's hidden by default, and visible (with the animation you assign) when press the buton with [matMenuTriggerFor]
you can see examples working in the angular material documentation

Comment: could you make a stackblitz or angular playground demo?

Comment: hi, I apologize for the delay...
Yes, here have a demo on stackblitz   https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sjs1fx